# How do I change the base URL?

Tags: 8, uri

In Drupal 7, we can quickly change the base URL of the website.
How can I do this, in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Drupal 8 this option has been removed. You don't have to configure  `base_url` to run your site. Drupal 8 can detect this without your help. If not, you should first check your webserver configuration.

Instead of `base_url` you should configure `trusted_host_patterns` in settings.php. This is not needed to run the site, but important for security reasons.

More info: [Removed base_url option from settings.php](https://www.drupal.org/node/2529168) and [New setting for trusted hostname configuration](https://www.drupal.org/node/2410395)

Edit:

There are some special use cases when running drupal from command line or reverse proxy, that used $base_url in the past. This can no longer be supported in the same way because of symfony. There is a discussion going on how to provide a solution for these cases. This does not mean that you cannot run drupal from the command line or reverse proxy. The standard way is of course possible without problems.

You can follow the development here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2753591

Answer (score 10):

I thought once some kind of tweaks were needed when moving between production (http:// example.com/) and dev (http:// localhost/~aviram/example.com/). But no, D8 is smart enough to fix links automatically.

After moving a complete site (PHP files and DB dump), just go through the D8 database update process (**http://example.com/update.php**) even if there is no update for the database model. This fixes the problem.

I learned this is a Drupal 8 cache-related problem probably because some pre-rendered content is kept in sites/default/files/php/. And the update.php process somehow cleans this cache.

Comment: Yes, /update.php always clears the cache, even if there are no updates to run. This is a nice trick to get a site running after moving it to a new place, if you don't want or can't access another method to clear the cache.