# Drupal in sub directory, still not clear

Tags: 8

My drupal project is in directory `/var/www/MY_ORGANIZATION/MY_PROJECT/current`, and apache2 is configured to point the `web` subdirectory of the above location. When I access the site, it is of course under http://www.myorganization.it/. Now I need to move it to http://www.myorganization.it/myproject, both for organization policies and to allow it to be more easily reached through a reverse proxy. I searched around and I found a couple of interesting links, like [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199445/how-do-i-change-the-base-url) and [this](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/installing-drupal/2018-01-05/migrating-drupal-8-site-from-root-to-sub-directory) and a few more. Inspired by them, I tried to move the contents of `web/` to `web/myproject`, but when I accessed http://www.myorganization.it/myproject I got blank page. The error in the logs is crystal clear:

```
Failed opening required '/var/www/MY_ORGANIZATION/MY_PROJECT/current/web/myproject/../vendor/autoload.php'
```

So I put back the installation in `web/` and renamed it to `myproject`, changed apache configuration to point `/var/www/MY_ORGANIZATION/MY_PROJECT/current`, and that worked like a charm. But I am not sure this is an advisable configuration, since, well, since all Drupal installations I saw were in a `web` directory. Also, from my research I had understood that Drupal installation can be moved to arbitrary subdirectories, but I didn't find any official documentation. It would appear that I should at least configure a path for `vendor`.

So, the concluding question is, would you recommend simply renaming `web` to `myproject`, or should I do it another way?

EDIT: a symlink from `myproject` to `web` seems an elegant solution, it works fine in apache (dev environment), while I'm getting errors with nginx+php-fpm (staging environment); still, it may be the way to go.

Comment: To clarify the error message you're seeing in the log: this is coming from PHP rather than Apache. When `index.php` is run it (indirectly) looks for a file with the _relative_ path `../vendor/autoload.php`. If the contents of `web` are moved, this relative path to `../vendor` stops being correct.

Answer (score 1):

Apache can handle this. You can leave the Drupal code where it is.

Have a look at the Apache documentation for [Mapping URLs to Filesystem Locations](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/urlmapping.html). In particular, the differences between `DocumentRoot` and `Alias`.

In the absence of any other information, Apache looks for files/scripts in the document root. For a Drupal site located at `https://www.myorganization.it/`, it's enough to point `DocumentRoot` at the `web` directory. Apache will find `index.php` there.

But `myproject` isn't a directory in the filesystem. So you need to explicitly tell Apache about it, that any URL starting `/myproject` refers to the `web` directory. You can do that with the `Alias` directive:

`Alias "/myproject" "/var/www/MY_ORGANIZATION/MY_PROJECT/current/web"`

You'll also want to point `DocumentRoot` somewhere else to stop Drupal being visible at the root too (an empty directory will do).

Comment: Yes, I know, but then all the links to static files will be wrong, and I'd have to set `file_public_base_url` to change that; it seems easier to me to just put everything in a separated directory, from my research it appears to be a supported configuration, but it's not clear to me what is the recommended way to do it.